# Does Java's UrlConnection buffer the whole download in memory?

Tags: java, streaming, httpurlconnection

I'm using HttpURLConnection to download files using Java.

As the data is streamed, I'm transferring it to circular buffers which are by nature limited in the amount of memory they consume.

However, does HttpURLConnection store the entire stream in memory itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no, otherwise a java program would never be able to download anything very large.  (it's possible that small responses are fully buffered in memory).

Comment: Makes sense. Just needed a quick sanity check. Thanks.